# ORACLE'S UTL_TCP EQUIVALENT in POSTGRES

Tags: oracle, postgresql, migration

I'm working on a migration project from ORACLE to POSTGRES, and I need to find an equivalent of UTL_TCP for postgres , Is there any extension I should add or something like this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent for that in PostgreSQL.

What I would do is write a function in [PL/PerlU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl.html) or [PL/PythonU](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) that accesses the network.

Comment: Do you mind providing a snippet of code to see how it should look like ? Thank you